# List Activity not starting

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, arraylist

```
private ListView listView;
private List<String> userNames,desc,lat,lon,image, placeNames;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_list);
    setTitle("Places List");

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.placesListView);
    userNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    placeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    desc=new ArrayList();image=new ArrayList();
    lat=new ArrayList();lon=new ArrayList();



    userNames=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("userNames");
    placeNames=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("placeNames");
    desc=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("desc");
    image=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("image");
    lat=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lat");
    lon=getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("lon");

    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userNames);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object referencejava.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
How to avoid the exception?

Comment: The List 'userNames' is null somehow, check that !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you are trying to set userNames in adapter then it will occur just because you are getting userNames list as null so first check and then set like below

```
if(userNames!=null){
final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userNames);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Now the app is not crashing , but list isn't displaying. 
I am able to display values in invoking activity.    
    `enter code here`
if(userNames.size()>0)
{
    Log.i("OOOOOOO",userNames.get(0)+"'"+userNames.get(1));
}        
Intent intent=new Intent(ViewActivity.this,PlacesListActivity.class);        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("userNames",userNames);intent.putStringArrayListExtra("placeNames",placeNames);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("desc",desc);intent.putStringArrayListExtra("image",image);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lat",lat);intent.putStringArrayListExtra("lon",lon);
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewActivity.this,PlacesListActivity.class));
```

Comment: If I include the same log statement                            .................................................................................................................if(placeNames.size()>0){{ 
  Log.i("OOOOOOO",placeNames.get(0)+"'"+placeNames.get(1));}.......................in the List activity,  the exception is repeated

Comment: Instead of `startActivity(new Intent(ViewActivity.this,PlacesListActivity.class));` change to `startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Debug and make sure all arrayList has data in `ViewActivity` class.